# How do I remove all items starting with a letter chosen by the user?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing an assignment for school. I'm supposed to let the user make a list of ten words, and then I'm supposed to remove all the items in the list that start with a letter chosen by the user.
This is how I tried to do it, but it doesn't remove all the words that start with the letter. 
I've troubleshooted as much as I'm able to with my limited knowledge, and It looks like the for loop just isn't going through all the words.

```
ordalisti = []
for i in range(10):
    wordlist.append(str(input("Type a word: ").lower()))
letter = input("Choose a letter: ").lower()
for word in wordlist:
    if word[0] == letter:
        wordlist.remove(word)
print(wordlist)
```

Comment: `ordalisti = []` should be `wordlist= []` also your indentation is a bit off...

Answer (score 2):

Removing items from a list *as you're iterating over it* doesn't work.  The act of removal interferes with the iteration sequence and it ends up skipping some items.

One way around this is to copy the items you want to save into a new list, and then replace the old list with the new list.

Take a look at the answers to this existing question for lots of ways to [handle removing items from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating).

Comment: For minimal change, you could just do `for word in wordlist.copy()`

Comment: Thanks! I ended up adding the items which didn't start with the chosen letter, to a new list, and then replacing the old list with the new one, like you said.

Answer (score 2):

You could use list comprehension:

```
print [word for word in wordlist if word[0] != letter]
```

Comment: I think you want `if word[0] != letter`

Comment: Thanks for catching this.

Answer (score -1):

```
wordlist = []

for i in range(10):
    wordlist.append(input("Type a word: ").lower().strip())

letter = input("Choose a letter: ").lower().strip()

new_wordlist = [word for word in wordlist if not word.startswith(letter)]

print(new_wordlist)
```

Comment: code-only answers are not as helpful as the ones explaining why the OP has a problem and why your code fixes it.

Answer (score -2):

I think instead of `ordalisti = []` you need `wordlist = []`.  And your indentation is a bit off, beginning with that first variable declaration.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: I don't have enough permissions to comment.

Comment: ...except on my own answer apparently...

Comment: Sorry, I translated it from ordalisti to wordlist for the sake of english speakers understanding it, I must've forgotten to translate the top one. :P

Comment: To the downvoters- Am I getting downvoted for attempting to assist the OP in answering their question using the only means (an answer) that I'm allowed.  If so, this is not a system that encourages participation, but rather restricts participation to those with the powers that be.